# Resetting variables is not resetting game?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a Simon game and it works on round one, but once your each round two it immediately says incorrect.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dfk2am7e/)

I reset all variables between the rounds, but it still seems to save them as it instantly says "Game Over!"

JS:

```
function makeGuess() {
    ...
    var checkForComplete = setInterval(function () {
        if (yourAnswer.length >= round) {
            clearInterval(checkForComplete);
            yourString = yourAnswer.toString();
            correctString = correctAnswer.toString();
            if (yourString === correctString) {
                alert('Correct');
                round++;
                yourAnswer = [];
                correctAnswer = [];
                yourString = "";
                correctString = "";
                playSimon();
            }
            else {
                alert("Game Over!");
            }
        }
    }, 500)
```

Here is the playSimon() function:

```
function playSimon() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        color = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
        if (color == 0) {
            correctAnswer.push(0);
            $('#redButton').addClass('lightOn');
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#redButton').removeClass('lightOn');
            }, 500);
        }
        else if (color == 1) {
            correctAnswer.push(1);
            $('#blueButton').addClass('lightOn');
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#blueButton').removeClass('lightOn');
            }, 500);
        }
        else if (color == 2) {
            correctAnswer.push(2);
            $('#greenButton').addClass('lightOn');
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#greenButton').removeClass('lightOn');
            }, 500);
        }
        else if (color == 3) {
            correctAnswer.push(3);
            $('#yellowButton').addClass('lightOn');
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#yellowButton').removeClass('lightOn');
            }, 500);
            }
        i++;
        if (i <= round) {
            playSimon();
        }
        else {
            makeGuess();
        }
    }, 700);
}
```

Why is it alerting Game Over instantly on round 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are binding the click events multiple times:

```
function makeGuess() {
    $('#redButton').click(function() {
        yourAnswer.push(0);
    });
    $('#blueButton').click(function() {
        yourAnswer.push(1);
    });
    $('#greenButton').click(function() {
        yourAnswer.push(2);
    });
    $('#yellowButton').click(function() {
        yourAnswer.push(3);
    });

    ...
}
```

Each time makeGuess() is called, the buttons are bound yet another click event listener. First time it's done (first level), there's only 1 event listener so it's working correctly, but from the second level onward each buttons are bound with 2 identical click listener, and when the player click a button, the function is called twice => yourAnswer is pushed twice immediately, which result in an incorrect answer => game over.

A quick fix is to [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) all click events on the 4 buttons before binding them all again, optimally immediately before the next playSimon() is called.

```
if (yourString === correctString) {
            alert('Correct');
            round++;
            yourAnswer = [];
            correctAnswer = [];
            yourString = "";
            correctString = "";

            $('#redButton').unbind( "click" );
            $('#blueButton').unbind( "click" );
            $('#greenButton').unbind( "click" );
            $('#yellowButton').unbind( "click" );
            playSimon();
        } else {
            alert("Game Over!");
        }
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dfk2am7e/1/

Answer (score 0):

AVAVT is right, however instead of unbinding, rather just bind the event once off.

I have updated your JSFiddle and optimized your code a little bit.

https://jsfiddle.net/dfk2am7e/3/

```
// Run this when the page has loaded to ensure HTML is there.
$(function(){
    $('#redButton').click(function() {
        yourAnswer.push(0);
      });
      $('#blueButton').click(function() {
        yourAnswer.push(1);
      });
      $('#greenButton').click(function() {
        yourAnswer.push(2);
      });
      $('#yellowButton').click(function() {
        yourAnswer.push(3);
      });
});
```